# Getting an error when running "npx wdio config"

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webdriver-io

I get the following error when I try to set up "Hello World" test suite into my project by running: "npx wdio config". I followed the instructions on the https://webdriver.io/docs/gettingstarted and still not able to get it to work.

Can someone help me with resolving this:

```
WDIO Configuration Helper


? Where is your automation backend located? (Use arrow keys)
❯ On my local machine 
  In the cloud using Experitest 
  In the cloud using Sauce Labs 
  In the cloud using Browserstack or Testingbot or LambdaTest or a different service 
  I have my own Selenium cloud (node:2831) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'find' of undefined
    at Object.run (/Users/gustavosuarez/web/mo-appium-wdio-jasmine/node_modules/@wdio/cli/build/index.js:67:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/gustavosuarez/web/mo-appium-wdio-jasmine/node_modules/@wdio/cli/bin/wdio.js:11:21)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:72:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be a problem with the latest version of the `@wdio/cli` dependency. I solved the problem by using an older version and it works now (`"@wdio/cli": "7.3.1"`). Just add that dependency to your package.json and run `yarn` or `npm install` again, then `npx wdio config` and it should work.